# Customer interactive vector map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, dictionary

I'm sure this isn't going to be straight forward, however..I have a custom vector map of the UK and it's an animated map. It shows different locations all over the country and I need to be able to allow the user to click on a certain location on the map. So the user will get a pop up about the location they've selected. Something like this - http://jqvmap.com/ However like i said the map has charactertures on it.

I'm wondering how simple it would be to change the co-ordinates in the Javascript to locate the positions on the map. Is there a tool I can get so it tells you your current co-ords on hover to help?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated! It needs to work on all major browsers including IE 8/9 (7 if possible).

Thanks,

Josh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found something that seems to have done the trick - http://www.outsharked.com/imagemapster/default.aspx?demos.html#frog

I've implemeted the code onto my page and it's worked. I've managed to get the co-ordinates from the web developer tool bar.

However, I'd like to implement a zoom in feature, where you can zoom and move around the image as if you were using google maps. So you can scroll with the house. My worry is will that lose the co-ordinates on the image? As I still want users to be able to click on the locations on the map.